# How to group and split items in a list by inline code?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working with database. I wanna get all messages and group them based on `RoomId` (1 conversation contains the message(s) with the same `RoomId`).

I've tried this:

```
public class Message
{
    public string SenderId { get; set; }

    public string ReceiverId { get; set; }

    public string RoomId { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Message>
            {
                new Message { SenderId = "Sender1", ReceiverId = "Receiver1", RoomId = "Room2" },
                new Message { SenderId = "Sender1", ReceiverId = "Receiver1", RoomId = "Room1" },
                new Message { SenderId = "Sender1", ReceiverId = "Receiver1", RoomId = "Room3" },
                new Message { SenderId = "Sender1", ReceiverId = "Receiver1", RoomId = "Room1" },
                new Message { SenderId = "Sender1", ReceiverId = "Receiver1", RoomId = "Room2" },
                new Message { SenderId = "Sender1", ReceiverId = "Receiver1", RoomId = "Room3" }
            };

        var group_list = list.GroupBy(x => x.RoomId);

        var output_list = new List<List<Message>>();

        foreach (var item in group_list)
        {
            output_list.Add(item.ToList());
        }

        foreach (var item in output_list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Conversation {output_list.IndexOf(item) + 1}");

            foreach (var msg in item)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"SenderId: {msg.SenderId}\tReceiverId: {msg.ReceiverId}\tRoomId: {msg.RoomId}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output snapshot]

I wanna inline the part:

```
foreach (var item in group_list)
{
    output_list.Add(item.ToList());
}
```

to:

```
var group_list = list.GroupBy(x => x.RoomId).[...what's next?...];
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `GroupBy` you select the group which is `IEnumerable<Message>`, so you can use `ToList`:

```
List<List<Message>> output_list = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.RoomId)
    .Select(g => g.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Should mention the IGrouping with the key. Sure it still derives from `IEnumerable<T>`, but still worth mentioning

Comment: @Nkosi: in my opinion that just distracts from the fact that it's an `IEnumerable<T>` so you can use all LINQ methods there. The key is also not needed here. But of course you're right, you get a special type which just implements `IEnumerable<T>`.